# how to make slick display image in right order?

Tags: css, vue.js, carousel, slick.js, horizontal-scrolling

I am using slick to get horizontal slider of images.what I wish to get is on clicking right arrow to see more images but that button is not working rather left button clicks and shows black screens which should not happen how should I implement this?
Below is my code:

```
 <template>
<div>
       <slick
               ref="slick"
               :options="slickOptions"
           >
                <img
            
             :data-lazy="
               
                 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(35).jpg&width=150&enforceAspectRatio=true'
           
             " style="width:200px; height:200px "
           />
    .
   .
   .same image tag 10 times
   .
   .
   .
   .
    
    <img
            
             :data-lazy="
               
                 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(35).jpg&width=150&enforceAspectRatio=true'
           
             " style="width:200px; height:200px "
           />
           </slick>
   </div>
   </template>
```

what I wish to get is on clicking right arrow to see more images but that button is not working rather left button clicks and shows black screens which should not happen how should I implement this?
below images show what I mean.

```
slickOptions: {
                infinite: false,
                adaptiveHeight: false,
                //variableWidth: true,
                draggable: true,
                edgeFriction: 0.3,
                slidesToShow: 6,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 1024,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 6,
                            slidesToScroll: 3,
                            infinite: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 641,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            slidesToScroll: 2,
                            initialSlide: 2
                        }
                    }
                    }
                ],
                swipe: true,
                rows: 0,
                prevArrow:
                    '<div class="back-arrow"><i class="icons" aria-hidden="true">&#xe830;</i></div>',
                nextArrow:
                    '<div class="forward-arrow"><i class="icons" aria-hidden="true">&#xe803;</i></div>',
            },
            currentLocale: "",
            showList: true,
        };
```

```
created() {
        
            this.slickOptions.prevArrow =
                '<div class="forward-arrow"><i class="icons" aria-hidden="true">&#xe803;</i></div>';
            this.slickOptions.nextArrow =
                '<div class="back-arrow"><i class="icons" aria-hidden="true">&#xe830;</i></div>';
            this.slickOptions.rtl = true;
            }
```

what I wish to get is on clicking right arrow to see more images but that button is not working rather left button clicks and shows black screens which should not happen how should I implement this?
below images show what I mean.

[image: 1st image]

[image: second image]

Comment: Please create an [mcve], like stack snippet or codesandbox

Comment: hi @TJ, I have added all possible things require to reproduce the same condition.
I made few changes please tell me what else is needed  ?

Comment: I think your created() function is changing rtl order which is causing issues. It also has the setting for `infinite: false`

Comment: for some reason infinite = true, doesn't renders anything.